# Is Leviticus 20:18 still in effect today?

Tags: leviticus

Leviticus 20:18

> 18 If a man lies with a woman during her menstrual period and uncovers her nakedness, he has made naked her fountain, and she has uncovered the fountain of her blood. Both of them shall be cut off from among their people.

Has Leviticus 20:18 been done with just like the laws of the unclean food?

Comment: Sorry, but contemporary application is off-topic here. If you'd like to know what Judaism teaches about this law, you can ask at [judaism.se], or one of the Christian denominations, at [Christianity.se].

Comment: @curiousdannii If "contemporary application is off-topic here," what in the world are we here for?  If Biblical hermeneutics have nothing to do with "today"--we might as well close down the entire site as a waste of time.  Sorry, but I really don't get it.  Where is the rule that says we are disallowed to make application of the Bible for "today"?  I would like to know where commoners like myself can lodge an official complaint and/or suggestion to change the rules here.  This is, in the words of the Preacher, vanity.  And insanity.

Comment: @Polyhat The purpose of this site is the study of Biblical passages to understand their meaning. Determining which parts, if any, of the Israelite Law are binding on present populations falls under Systematic Theology, which is off-topic here, but can be asked at those other sites. Note that many *answers* will go beyond what a question asks to make comments applying the text to today, and that's okay; what isn't is *questions* which centre on systematic theology. I'm sorry you feel this is insanity, but this is how it's always been since the site was founded.

Comment: @curiousdannii If they cannot apply to us today, it is impossible for there to be any real "meaning" in them.  It would seem, then, that the site's rules contradict its own purpose.

Comment: @Polyhat Are the laws of any other country than your own completely without meaning? Of course not. Just because a law isn't binding on you doesn't mean you can't learn from it, can't learn about its author(s), its culture, its moral backing. I don't have to be a Jew living in ancient Israel to learn from their laws what God is like. Of course many Jews and Christians say the Israelite Law does at least in part still bind people today, but that's a matter for the other sites, not this one. Or at least not for a passage like this. We can ask what Matthew 5:17 etc mean on this site.

Comment: @Polyhat https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/election/2 if you run, I'll vote for you :)

Comment: @TonyChan  I've been quite resistant to the notion simply because it's a considerable responsibility, a lot of work, and generally a thankless job.  I've been a mod on other forums.  I suppose I do well, but I prefer to just participate without the stress.  If there's really a need, I have a hard time turning down a request for help, but usually someone else will be eager to moderate.  Thanks for the vote of confidence, though!

Comment: @PolyHat - soliciting contemporary applications is off topic as it conflicts with trying to exegete texts in their own context. Providing contemporary application is at the Answerer's own choice.

Comment: @Polyhat - You're sort of right on your point about Answers being moderated less than Questions - SE is primarily geared around well-asked questions, and has far better processes around the scoping of questions to manage the content. For example users can vote to Close a question, but Answers can only be downvoted, and Deletion is often a bit drastic.

Comment: Questions essentially should "arise from a text", so they're primarily about reading meaning out of a particular text, rather than being anchored on theological questions, which is more what Christianity.SE is there to explore.

Comment: We aren't here for "questions that can be answered from the Bible", but rather for "questions about and starting from Biblical texts". The rationale was built on many years in 'Beta' gradually refining the guidelines to produce useful and answerable questions :)

Comment: @SteveTaylor I thought I'd understood that Christianity.SE was more sectarian, and the BH was non-sectarian and strictly focused on hermeneutics--which is why I am here at BH and not at C.SE.

Comment: @PolyHat - that's sort of my point. Lots of people want to approach the Bible with a lean towards their own preferred doctrines and readings - which is what C.SE offers - and don't really like the text-first approach of exegesis. As somebody who preaches, I really value hermeneutics as a tool for analysing the text in its own right, as it was intended to be understood, before we try and carry our own intentions and motives to it. It's the first and most critical step in the process of theologising those texts - it's a space where we should be able to engage freely regardless of our theologies.

Answer (score 1):

> And if a man shall lie with a woman having her sickness, and shall
> uncover her nakedness; he hath discovered her fountain, and she hath
> uncovered the fountain of her blood: and both of them shall be cut off
> from among their people. (Leviticus 20:18, KJV)

**Does this Law Still Apply?**

In order to determine whether this law still applies, one must first ask whether or not the law has been abolished.  If it has not been abolished, then it would still apply.

Many of the laws in ancient Israel came with severe punishments for offenders--such as the death penalty.  Breaking one of the Ten Commandments could incur the death penalty.  Does God expect us to kill commandment-breakers today?  No, because God has placed this authority with our civil government.

It would not be right to attempt to execute the law privately when it is now the jurisdiction of the government to handle such matters.  This is why Jesus faced the challenge from the Pharisees over the woman caught in adultery, and Jesus did not command that she be stoned, as the law had prescribed.

Yet, because the *consequence* for the crime seems to be withheld, it does not follow that the law against adultery (the seventh commandment) no longer applies.  Jesus told the woman to "go and sin no more."  He did NOT say it wasn't a sin anymore!

That same principle must be carefully considered with respect to the Levitical laws.  Just because they are not enforced with harsh penalties does not mean that God has removed or changed the laws.  Unless and until God has indicated a change, it is our duty (and should be our joy) to follow His laws.

There was a class of laws, called "ordinances," which centered around the types and ceremonies of the sacrificial system.  The death of Jesus on the cross fulfilled these types, and forever abolished their requirement.  It is for this reason that we no longer need to offer the blood of animals to atone for our sins--for Christ's blood has replaced, and superseded, all of those sacrifices.  People frequently refer to these laws as "Levitical laws," because they were integral to the Levitical priesthood and the priestly system.

It should be noted that the "Levitical laws" are not directly associated with the book of "Leviticus" per se, and, in fact, are scattered across the books of Exodus, Leviticus, Numbers, and Deuteronomy--each of these books having important truths that still apply to our time.  Jesus thrice quoted from Deuteronomy when facing the temptations in the wilderness, and his reiteration of the two most important commandments--love to God (Deut. 6:5), and love to one's neighbor (Lev. 19:18)--came from both Deuteronomy and Leviticus.

Many today clamoring to support the belief that the Levitical laws have been abolished find themselves at odds with some portion of them and wish to soothe their consciences.  For quite a few, it's the laws governing marriage and sexuality that they find objectionable.  For some it's the health laws regulating diet and habits of cleanliness and sanitation.

One's concept of God factors large into whether or not he or she will believe these laws still apply: Does God want us to be happy? Does He know best?  Are these laws merely arbitrary?  Did God love only the Jews, and give His laws only for their benefit?

These are questions each one must answer to his or her own satisfaction.  As the Bible says:

> One man esteemeth one day above another: another esteemeth every day
> alike. Let every man be fully persuaded in his own mind. (Romans 14:5,
> KJV)

I would submit that the laws called "ordinances" which dealt with the priestly sacrificial system are the only ones to have been abolished.  These are specified in two important verses in the New Testament.

> Having abolished in his flesh the enmity, even the law of commandments
> **contained in ordinances**; for to make in himself of twain one new man, so making peace; (Ephesians 2:15, KJV)
>
> Blotting out **the handwriting of ordinances** that was against us,
> which was contrary to us, and took it out of the way, nailing it to
> his cross; (Colossians 2:14, KJV)

All other laws are still in place, and they apply equally to all people.  Jesus said: "If ye love me, keep my commandments" (John 14:15, KJV).

**Conclusion**

Not being a part of the sacrificial law, which was abolished, but rather a health law, I would submit that the law of Leviticus 20:18 is still applicable today.

Comment: Please consider voting to close off-topic questions rather than answering them in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Many *principles* found in Leviticus need to be considered, even ‘today’. However, the *consequences* of violating Torah **only** apply to those ‘under the Law’.

> **ROMANS 6:14** *for sin over you shall not have lordship, for ye are not under law, but under grace.*

The Jews now have a release, and ‘we’ (gentiles) were never ‘under’ Law, so Leviticus does *not* apply - but note my first sentence.

Comment: Please consider voting to close off-topic questions rather than answering them in the future.

Answer (score 0):

There are three kinds of laws:

- Levitical laws describing how the priesthood should operate.
- Civil laws describing how the physical nation of Israel should operate.
- Eternal laws describing how mankind should operate.

The Levitical laws ended with the destruction of the Temple in 70 CE and the end of the priesthood.

The Civil laws are still followed to a large extent by modern Jews.

Neither the Civil nor the Levitical laws were ever intended for anyone not a part of the physical nation of Israel.

But the Eternal laws have always been in effect for everyone.

Leviticus 20:18 is clearly a Civil law, as it regulates society and the punishment imposed by that society.
The law is still binding on modern Jews (though the punishment is no longer practiced).

The laws of unclean food were known long before Israel (e.g. Noah knew about unclean and clean animals).
The Bible describes unclean food as an abomination to God.
These laws are obviously neither Levitical nor Civil, and so are still in effect for everyone.

Comment: I would broadly agree.  However, the distinction between these side-by-side laws is not simple and there has been much debate about which of the laws are still in effect.

Comment: Please consider voting to close off-topic questions rather than answering them in the future.

Comment: @curiousdannii, Right.  If there hadn't already been an answer, I think I wouldn't have.added my own.